# Getting warnings when implementing Facebook Pixel

Tags: reactjs, warnings, production-environment

I'm using Facebook pixel to track user events in my reactjs web application and after some tries i was able to implement it. But i'm getting a warning which prevents me from from building my web application to use in production. It works in localhost but cannot build for production.

The warning i'm getting

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

My Pixel Code used in App.js

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?

      n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
      if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
      n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
      t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)
      f.fbq('init', '12*****733520546');
      f.fbq('track', 'PageView');}(window, document,'script',
      'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
```

What's wrong with the function i have used. How can i fix this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by initializing the function to a variable. Example below

```js
var fbPixel = function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
            n.callMethod ?
            n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
        };
        if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0';
        n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
        t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    } (window, document, 'script',
        'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
        /*global fbq*/
        /*eslint no-undef: "error"*/
        fbq("init", "12*****733520546")
        fbq("track", "PageView");

        return !fbPixel;
```

So you can wrap this in a function and just call the function